# Applying Burnside Lemma to board game

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Pentago is a board game with a field with 36 points on an 6x6 board. The board is divided into 4 smaller squares which are 3x3 points big. Each of these smaller squares can be rotated. On each field, either a white marble, black marble or nothing can be placed
[image]

The question is, how many possible board positions exist, that are not equivalent to something you could get by turning the squares or looking at the game at another angle?

I tried to tackle this problem with group theory by applying the Burnside Lemma.

Here are the permutations and the corresponding amount of cycles i have came up with:

identity - 36 cycles 
rotating whole board - 9 cycles 
rotating small square 1 - 30 cycles 
rotating small square 2 - 30 cycles 
rotating small square 3 - 30 cycles 
rotating small square 4 - 30 cycles 
mirroring at diagonal axis 1 - 21 cycles 
mirroring at diagonal axis 2 - 21 cycles 
mirroring at horizontal axis 1 - 18 cycles 
mirroring at horizontal axis 2 - 18 cycles

Each field can either be empty, white or black (3 states), so by plugging in these numbers in the equation we get

$\frac{1}{10}\left(3^{36}+3^{9}+4 \times 3^{30}+2 \times 3^{21}+2 \times 3^{18}\right) = \frac{75459110760472392}{5}$

There must be a mistake somewhere, because this is not an integer. Does anyone have a clue, what could be the mistake?

Comment: Are you allowed to rotate a small square twice, that is, but $180^\circ$?  Are you allowed to rotate two or more small squares?

Comment: Yes, each permutation can be apllied any number of times

Comment: The group order is a great deal larger than $10$.  We can rotate each of the $4$ small squares $0$ to $3$ times, giving $4^4=256$.  Then we can apply any of the $8$ symmetries of the large square, bringing us up to $2048$ at least.  I don't know if this exhausts the group or not.  What if we rotate a small square, reflect the large square and rotate a small square?  Is this a group element other than those I have considered?

Comment: You need to specify the symmetry group you're allowing more carefully... certainly there aren't just $10$ elements.  Even just allowing rotations of the entire board gives $4$ group elements.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel The OP mentions "mirroring at diagonal", so I take it that the answer is "yes."

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentago) gives a count of configurations.